# The behaviour of two links named "unanswered" is different

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Clicking the "Unanswered" link in the top-level navigation menu:

[image: The "Unanswered" link in the top-level navigation menu]

…shows questions that have no answers at all, whereas clicking "Questions", then selecting "unanswered" in the second-level navigation menu:

[image: The "unanswered" link in the second-level navigation menu]

…shows questions which have no accepted answer.

Why should two links that are apparently intended to list unanswered questions show different results? I almost always forget which link does what.

Surely they should be labelled differently if their behaviour is different?

Comment: The naming mix up is unfortunate, but they *are* clearly different tab levels. Honestly I'm not sure why the secondary Unanswered tab exists under Questions though...it's basically the same content as the top level Unanswered tab without the sorting options.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

The original meaning of "unanswered" was:

> Questions that have no **upvoted** answer.

Some people thought that this was misleading so the ability to find truly unanswered questions was added.

I agree that the nomenclature is ambiguous, but I think it's a bit late to change now - unless you can come up with a really good name.

Comment: is there a reason we have the unanswered subtab of questions? It seems unnecessary with the top level Unanswered tab

Comment: @Ben You'd have to raise that with an employee :)